# Is there an automated way to replace several layers with a template layer in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting

I have a file where there are several "cards" that will be containing text information. All of these cards are exactly the same but have been aligned differently. Unfortunately, I have to replace all of these cards with a new template that I have created. Is there a way to do so without having to manually replace all the layers individually and realign them?[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you are using ordinary layers I don't think there is an easy way to replace each layer.

One way to do this is to use *Smart Objects*.

- Right-click the initial layer and choose *Convert to Smart Object*.
- Duplicates of the smart object are all references to the same layer.
- When you double-click one of the duplicates the smart object will open in a new window. You can edit it, save it and close it. The changes will be reflected in all the duplicates.

Since you are talking about also adding text information to each card you might want to look into using a layout application like Illustrator or InDesign instead of Photoshop. I believe it will be *much* easier in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

Semi-easy version :)

- convert each layer to a smart object manually or using [this script](https://scriptorator.readthedocs.io/en/latest/soselected/index.html);
- RMB on the new smart objects and select `Convert to Linked`. Photoshop will ask for a folder to export all smarts as files;
- delete all `.psb` files but one;
- back to PS: start recording a new action: rmb on one layer and select `Relink to file`, select one file that left;
- play this action on all other layers